# elem is undefined?

Tags: javascript, dom, element, getelementsbytagname

When I run the following piece of code, the firebug console says that elem is undefined, although...it isn't!

```
var domTools = {};
domTools.searchInElements = function (elem, pattern) {
    if (pattern.constructor !== RegExp) {
        throw "Pattern must be a RegExp";
    }
    if (elem.constructor !== String) {
        throw "Element must be a String";
    }
    elem = document.getElementsByTagName[elem];
    var matches = [];
    for (e = 0; e < elem.length; e++) {
        if (pattern.test(elem[e].innerHTML)) {
            matches.push(elem[e]);
        }
    }
    return matches;
}
domTools.searchInElements("p", /hello/);
```

It gives me the error during the `for` statement. All this code is being run whle the page is already loaded. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4):

It's `()` and not `[]`

```
elem = document.getElementsByTagName(elem);
```

Think of `getElementsByTagnName()` as a function call so you won't forget that it uses `()`. And don't forget using the developer console <kbd>F12</kbd> to spot these problems.

Answer (score 3):

As [Joseph the Dreamer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/575527/joseph-the-dreamer) already found the bug that was causing the error because you've used `document.getElementsByTagName[elem]`instead of`document.getElementsByTagName(elem)`.

But you may face another problem with this call `domTools.searchInElements("p", /hello/);` because it'll match `hello, helloo, hellos etc` so you should use

```
domTools.searchInElements("p", /^hello$/)
```

OR just another idea [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/UH67r/1/).

Comment: +1 but also note that using RegExp is slow. You could alternatively use `String.indexOf()` for searching strings.